# appstore delay for bugfix

Tags: iphone, appstore-approval

my app has been rejected during the appstore approval process due to the use of private API (I'm so stupid... moreover, theunique use was almost useless).

How long does it take to have my app reviewed this second time? I'm affraid I'll have to wait 7 more days... And, since yesterday noon it is freezed at "upload received".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i'm aware every time you submit a binary, whether altering an error because of rejection or not it takes as long as it takes.

In my experiences the waiting period for review has always been 7 days. However, in the run up to Christmas this can grow in excess of 2 week I have heard as people spam apple with apps attempting to get a Christmas day release date.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is the way that when I wrote what is new in app "bug fixes" it use to take 3 days, but when I wrote just new features it was always at least 7 days.